# How to avoid including all .js and .css files while using ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

How can we avoid including all .js and .css files in the index.html like in this example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ShowTrackr</title>
  <link href="favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ionicons/1.4.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="stylesheets/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" bs-navbar>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <span>Show<strong>Trackr</strong></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li data-match-route="/$"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li data-match-route="/add"><a href="/add">Add</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" ng-if="!currentUser">
    <li data-match-route="/login"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li data-match-route="/signup"><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" ng-if="currentUser">
    <li class="navbar-text" ng-bind="currentUser.email"></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div ng-view class="{{pageClass}}"></div>

<script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-strap.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="filters/fromNow.js"></script>
<script src="directives/uniqueEmail.js"></script>
<script src="directives/passwordStrength.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/detail.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/add.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/navbar.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/login.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/signup.js"></script>
<script src="services/auth.js"></script>
<script src="services/show.js"></script>
<script src="services/subscription.js"></script>

<!--<script src="app.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="templates.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

This code comes from this github : https://github.com/sahat/tvshow-tracker

The code is used for a tutorial : http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/

I'd like to do something like :

```
angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "homeCtrl"
            /*
               Here say to include in the same time specific .js
               (for example the one who contain the 'homeCtrl' controller) and .css
            */
        });
    }]);
```

Because with the html code above, there are going to be a lot of server requests and possibly useless (If the user don't use the whole application). I cannot imagine Google didn't think of it.

Comment: Use a build tool like gulp or grunt and minify/concatenate all the files.

Comment: Is there really no way to avoid including all ?

Comment: You have to either include all files or concat them to one. You can try using requireJS, if you really need to include only one js file in index.html

Comment: My take on this is [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy), using Require.js and r.js for the build and [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy) to concatenate the different views into separate bundles. It is still under development and far from being complete, but you may (or may not) get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tips ! But this is weird that Google didn't think of something about it. I mean in a huge application, there could be more than hundreds of includes... Especially if we write one directive/controller/... by file.

Answer (score 0):

You can inline the CSS and JS code in the view. If the view is cacheable it is not a big issue.

You may want to take a look  at http://webcomponents.org

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/